# Adding rows dynamically to a HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I have a asp.net web site that contains some tables. However these are not asp:Table i.e. they are simple HTML tables built this way:

```
 <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Now I would like to know if it's possible to add rows dynamically to this table from the code behind (i.e. C#) and if yes, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Web forms or MVC. I would suggest doing it in MVC for this type of thing, or if you are stuck with Web forms then make the table runat="server"

Comment: MVC . Its pretty simple to add rows to a asp:Table but no idea doing it for HTML tables .

Comment: refer to this post:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but there is the repeater-control in ASP.NET Webforms for this kind of stuff.

Here is a nice article introducing this conept: [Data Repeater Controls in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx)

I think this will be easier for you than hacking this with AJAX/JScript

Aside from this: Daniel Casserly is right - this is very easy if you do it in MVC (even easier if you use Razor-Syntax), as it would translate do something like:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            ... whatever you need here ...
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I knew somebody less lazy than me would write the Razor code. Thanks Carsten :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can give it an Id and Set runat="server" attribute and use it from code behind using Id you gave it

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow r=new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell c = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
            c.InnerText = "New Cell";
            r.Cells.Add(c);
            T.Rows.Add(r);
```

where T is the Id of your table

Comment: How do i add the css class to be associated with each row or element ? There seems to be no functionality to do that for these row and cell elements .

Comment: there is Cell.style property I guess this is where styles are added, I never tried it though

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JQuery but for that you will need to give and Id or class or just search for the table array and then inject rows to it

Comment: Oh yes , an ID can definitely be given . Is there any way i can do it without using JQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can:
follow this link:[Adding new rows to HTML table dynamically](http://forums.asp.net/t/1087746.aspx)

and this:[How Dynamically Add Rows into ASP.NET Table using C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1978-how-dynamically-add-rows-into-aspnet-table-using-csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to create the entire `HTML` table from the code behind.
For this we can add a literal and use it in the code behind to add a table structure from the code behind.

e.g. Lets make an `HTML` table of Birds detail. 
     Just to keep explanation short I have not included the data table part filled with birds detail.

```
if (dtBirdsDetail.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      litBirdsTable.Text = "<center><table id='tbldata' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>" + System.Environment.NewLine;
      litBirdsTable.Text += "<tr>";

      //add datatable columns to html table as heading
for (int liColumnIndex = 0; liColumnIndex < dtBirdsDetail.Columns.Count;liColumnIndex++)
       {
         litBirdsTable.Text += "<th>" + dtBirdsDetail.Columns[liColumnIndex].ColumnName 
                             + "</th>" +   System.Environment.NewLine;
       }
       litBirdsTable.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "</tr>";

       //add datatable rows to html table
       for (int liRowIndex = 0; liRowIndex < dtBirdsDetail.Rows.Count; liRowIndex++)
       {
         litBirdsTable.Text += "<tr>";
         litBirdsTable.Text += "<td>" + dtBirdsDetail.Rows[liRowIndex]["ID"] + "</td>" +              
                                System.Environment.NewLine;
         litBirdsTable.Text += "<td>" + dtBirdsDetail.Rows[liRowIndex]["BirdName"] + " 
                               </td>" + System.Environment.NewLine;
         litBirdsTable.Text += "<td>" + dtBirdsDetail.Rows[liRowIndex]["TypeOfBird"] + " 
                               </td>" + System.Environment.NewLine;
         litBirdsTable.Text += "<td>" + dtBirdsDetail.Rows[liRowIndex]["ScientificName"] 
                             + "</td>" + System.Environment.NewLine;
         litBirdsTable.Text += "</tr>";
       }
        litBirdsTable.Text += "</table></center>";
    }
```

For detailed explanation, visit this link:

http://codevariation.blogspot.com/2018/03/html-table-design-with-dynamic-data.html